# Oracle SQL return specific value from column, AND any nulls

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I have a list of values in a column with some rows still being null.

I need a list of rows with 1 specific value and I want to include any that are null.

I can get the specific value, or I can get the nulls.  But I cannot get both together.

```
SELECT source
FROM table
WHERE source = 'value1' OR source IS NULL
```

This option takes a LONG time to process, and does not include any null rows

I have also tried

```
WHERE source not in ('value2','value3','value4')
```

But this option excludes the nulls as well.

What I need my query to return is

```
value1
value1
null
value1
null
null
value1
```

Comment: `and does not include any null rows` ... can you show us what you mean by "null row" by means of some sample data?

Comment: post a [mcve] including all table DDL, sample data, expected output

Comment: If the first query didn't work then maybe you don't actually have any null values; if you think you do then maybe those are not really null - perhaps spaces or something that looks the same at first glance. You can `dump()` a value you think is null to check what it really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT source
FROM table
WHERE coalesce(source,'value1') = 'value1'
```

Comment: By adding the OR statement I was able to get the query return I was after.  Thank you everyone for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```sql
WITH        -- Sample data
    list_tbl AS 
        (   Select  'value1'  "VALS" From Dual Union All 
            Select  'value9'  "VALS" From Dual Union All
            Select  'value7'  "VALS" From Dual Union All
            Select  'value1'  "VALS" From Dual Union All
            Select  NULL      "VALS" From Dual Union All
            Select  'value1'  "VALS" From Dual Union All
            Select  'valueX'  "VALS" From Dual Union All
            Select  NULL      "VALS" From Dual Union All
            Select  NULL      "VALS" From Dual Union All
            Select  'value2'  "VALS" From Dual Union All 
            Select  'value3'  "VALS" From Dual Union All
            Select  'value1'  "VALS" From Dual 
        )
--
-- SQL
Select  VALS From list_tbl Where Nvl(VALS, 'value1') = 'value1' 
--
-- Result
VALS  
------
value1
value1
null
value1
null
null
value1
```

Where clause Nvl() function makes null values (if there are any) considered as your value of choice...

Your **first query results the same** with above sample data...

```sql
Select  VALS From list_tbl Where VALS = 'value1' Or VALS Is Null
```